# Creating a statistical table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I will be grateful if you can help in creating a statistical table. Actually my problem is mainly in the editing. Here is the table I am trying to create:

[image]

In the table, there should be C and C&T columns under both the ADF test and KPSS test columns. However, I cannot center the ADF test and KPSS columns, and I cannot place the values under each column exactly. C and C&T columns also do not fit under the At Level and First Difference columns.

The codes I use are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Summary statistics of the variables}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}l ccccp{1.5cm} p{0.5cm} ccccp{1.5cm}@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ADF Test} & \phantom{ab} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{KPSS Test} & \phantom{ab}\\ \cmidrule{2-5}\cmidrule{6-9}    
    & At Level & & First \newline Difference && At Level & & First \newline  Difference \\ \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
    Variables & C & C\&T & C & C\&T && C & C\&T & C & C\&T \\ \midrule
    vix & -59.907*** & -59.903*** & -4.382*** & -4.460 && 0.73 & 0.13 & 0.07 & -1.05 \\
    NSP & -0.74 & -2.16 & -6.98*** & -1.05 && 0.77 & 0.16 & 0.1 & -1.05\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of augmenting your code (added three lines at the top, and one at the bottom) in order to make it minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate part of page layout)

**Edit:**
MWE now consider @Mico suggestions (thank you very much, Mico!)

With use of `tabularray` package and its libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`. Since table is quite wide, reduced are font size and column separation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{round-mode=places, % <---added
             round-precision=2,
             tight-spacing,
             }
\caption{ADF and KPSS test of (non)stationarity}
    \centering
    \small                 % <---
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,   % <---
             colspec={@{} l *{2}{Q[c,si={table-format=-2.2{***} }]} % <--- changed
                                 Q[c,si={table-format=-1.2{***} }]  % <--- changed
                            *{5}{Q[c,si={table-format=-1.2}]}
                      @{} },
             row{1}={font=\bfseries} 
            }
    \toprule
    & \SetCell[c=4]{c} {{{ADF Test}}}    &   &   &    
        & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{KPSS Test}}}    &   &    &   \\ 
    \cmidrule[r]{2-5}  \cmidrule[l]{6-9}
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{At Level}}}    &   
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{1st Diff.}}}  &
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{At Level}}}  &
                & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{1st Diff.}}}  \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3}   \cmidrule[lr]{4-5} 
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-7}  \cmidrule[lr]{8-9}
Variables   & {{{C}}} & {{{C\&T}}}  
                & {{{C}}} & {{{C\&T}}}
                    & {{{C}}} & {{{C\&T}}}
                        & {{{C}}} & {{{C\&T}}}\\ 
    \midrule
vix         & -59.907*** 
                & -59.903***
                    & -4.382***
                        & -4.460
                            & 0.73
                                & 0.13
                                    & 0.07
                                        & -1.05 \\
NSP         & -0.74     
                & -2.16 
                    & -6.98*** 
                        & -1.05 
                            & 0.77 
                                & 0.16 
                                    & 0.1 
                                        & -1.05\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my comment under one of the other answers: It's not good form to write "Difference", as in these tests one can be dealing with both first and higher-order differences. Also, I think there's no reason for showing third decimals; 2 decimals should be more than enough (and eliminating them simplifies/streamlines the table noticeably).

Comment: @Mico, you are right. For my excuse, I just tried to reproduce desired form of table and consequently I didn't dig into the meaning of its content. I will edit my answer ASAP (hopefully site will be available next few hours) and  correct it considering your advice.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your answer Zarko, it really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I would use 8 `c` but no `p` columns for the 8 tests. I would also strive to use the same number of significant digits throughout. If need be, consider aligning the numbers on the decimal markers.

Oh, and do try to provide a caption that's a tad more informative than "Summary statistics of the variables". In the code below, I suggest "ADF and KPSS tests of (non)stationarity". [Aside: I'm an econometrician. I'm rather familiar with both ADF and KPSS tests, in no small part because the "P" in "KPSS" denotes the first letter of my thesis adviser's surname...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\sym[1]{\ifmmode{^{#1}}\else{$^{#1}$}\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of intercol. whitespace
\caption{ADF and KPSS tests of (non)stationarity\strut}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ADF Test} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{KPSS Test} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}    
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{At Level} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Diff.}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{At Level} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Diff.} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
    Variables & C & C\&T & C & C\&T & C & C\&T & C & C\&T \\ 
    \midrule
    VIX & $-$59.91\sym{***} & $-$59.90\sym{***} 
        &  $-$4.38\sym{***} & $ -$4.46 
        & 0.73 & 0.13 & 0.07 & $-$1.05 \\
    NSP & \hphantom{0}$-$0.74\hphantom{\sym{***}} 
        & \hphantom{0}$-$2.16\hphantom{\sym{***}} 
        & $-$6.98\sym{***} & $-$1.05 
        & 0.77 & 0.16 & 0.10 & $-$1.05\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for the help, the codes worked perfectly. By the way, the caption and values do not reflect the actual unit root results I have, just the random values and caption I put in because I am trying to create the table as a template first.

Comment: +1 and that is a cool remark: "[...] because the "P" in "KPSS" denotes the first letter of my thesis adviser's surname [...]"

Comment: Question: Is the `\newcommand\sym` a test for `math mode`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - The macro Isn't a test for math mode, it just *starts with* a test for math mode. If the condition is true, `^{#1}` is executed; if it's not, `$^{#1}$` is executed. I suppose the outer curly braces aren't necessary. Writing `newcommand\sym[1]{\ifmmode^{#1}\else$^{#1}$\fi}` would have been more parsimonious -- though not easier for humans to read.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Many thanks for my aside being a "cool remark". :-) My adviser (Peter Phillips) was one of the early researchers of the properties of various types of non-stationarity. My thesis didn't involve the ADF and KPSS tests, though. Instead, I looked into the properties of tests of constancy of (unconditional) *second moments* if the observed time series are leptokurtic ("heavy-tailed"). The asymptotic theory I developed relied heavily on the properties of stable distributions. I've pursued a non-academic career, but I've never regretted having written a "far-out" thesis. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I think that I might have a look at your thesis. At least at the first and last chapter.

Comment: @Mico I would also like to take a look at your thesis, it would be great if you could share a link where I can reach it directly.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner and Niki -- My actual thesis was "published" with *University Microfilms* in 1991; I have no idea how easy or difficult it is to order a copy from them. Anyway, I you *really* have a hankering for some of my published research in econometrics that relates to stable distributions, I can suggest (a) M. Loretan and P. Phillips, 1994, Testing the covariance stationarity of heavy-tailed economic time series: An overview of the theory with applications to financial datasets, *Journal of Empirical Finance*, vol. 1, no. 2, pp. 211-248 and ... (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued from preceding comment) ... (b) J.-R. Kurz-Kim and M. Loretan, 2014, On the properties of the coefficient of determination in regression models with infinite-variance variables, *Journal of Econometrics*, vol. 181, no. 1, pp. 15-24. The latter paper was written originally for a conference held in Eltville, Germany, on the occasion of Benoit Mandelbrot's 80th birthday in late-2006. I worked as an RA for Benoit Mandelbrot for about a year in the late 1980s. I suppose that's why I was invited to attend the conference... It took almost forever to get that paper published. Long story...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a look at the references. I really enjoy the community here, I learn about TeX and beyond.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - You're most welcome. A minor correction: The research conference in Eltville, Germany was held in late 2005, not late 2006.

Comment: I just now actually see that you wrote that you have worked for "The Mandelbrot"! Sometimes the text does not go from the eyes to the brain :). That's a cool side note.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to take into account @Mico 's comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Summary statistics of the variables}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{l *8c}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ADF Test} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{KPSS Test} \\ \cmidrule(rl){2-5}\cmidrule(rl){6-9}    
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{At Level }& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Difference} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{At Level }& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Difference} \\ \cmidrule(rl){2-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-5} \cmidrule(rl){6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
    Variables & C & C\&T & C & C\&T & C & C\&T & C & C\&T \\ \midrule
    vix & -59.907*** & -59.903*** & -4.382*** & -4.460 & 0.73 & 0.13 & 0.07 & -1.05 \\
    NSP & -0.74 & -2.16 & -6.98*** & -1.05 & 0.77 & 0.16 & 0.1 & -1.05\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For these tests, you can't just write "difference", as (depending on the circumstance) it could be the first, second or very (rarely) third difference. A separate issue: Your setup offers no assurance that the table will fit inside the text block. (In fact, when I compile your code, LaTeX complains that the table is ca 1.5cm too wide.)

Comment: Hi @Mico. I have delete inadvertently the word #First" before "Difference". You are write the table is too wide and we can fix it as you did by `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} `

Comment: One respect in which the table in "Zarko"'s answer is better than the one is this answer is that it uses genuine minus signs rather than hyphens. I presume you could get the same effect here by setting the numbers (including, of course, the minus signs) in math mode.

Comment: Thank you @Mico